# Remote Desktop Client toolbar default to pinned

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-server

One of our remote desktop client users likes to have the title bar always displayed. She used to be able to click the "tack" and pin the title bar down. However, the system is no longer remembering that setting. She has to pin the title bar each time she launches an RDP session. Is there a way to save that setting or alter the default behavior?

Comment: Is this related to a specific version of the client?

Comment: Yes, I would try updating the RDP client to latest version.

Answer (score 3):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal server Client "PinConnectionBar"=dword:00000001 works great.  Add it on the machine initiating thje session, not the one you are connecting to.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of my answer is what you are looking for but...

In the RDP connection options, in Display Tab, there is, at the bottom, the option:

*Display the connection bar when in full screen mode.*

And save it on your desktop.

I hope that helped!

David.

P.S. I would also update for the latest release of the RDP client.

Comment: The "Display the connection bar when in full screen mode" is checked but the bar still hides. 

I'm trying to find out which version of RDP client the user has but I'm not sure how to display the version number. mstsc doesn't provide any clues.

Comment: In previous version of Remote desktop client, if you check "Display the connection bar when in full screen mode", it will stay on top after you established connection.
In Ver 6.0, if this is checked, the connection bar starts in "auto hide" mode. You can push pushpin on left side of connection bar, and it will disable "auto hide" (bar will not go away).

You can also set this key as this:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal server Client
"PinConnectionBar"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

old thread I know, but just in case anyone else has this problem and wants an easier way to do this visit http://www.tiff-tools.com/rdppushpin.aspx for a small free utility to do the job.

Comment: And get malware installed for free? Although [Google says otherwise](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=www.tiff-tools.com) I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: I have used many tools from http://www.tiff-tools.com many times and they are always clean with absolutely no malware, so I find it very unfair of DeerHunters comments and down vote. Seems like a very nasty thing to do without any evidence.